# Finding change for a number

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I was given a project. What I have written down right now works for every number besides the one I need 83 where it says I don't need nickel when I do. I tried doing different operations but that messes the math up with the other numbers. If you could help that would be great.

```
total = int(input("Enter change [0...99]: "))
half = total // 50
quarter = total % 50 // 25
dimes = total % 25 // 10
nickels = total % 10 // 5
pennies = total % 5 // 1

print(half, "half (ves)")
print(quarter, "Quarter (s)")
print(dimes, "Dime (s)")
print(nickels, "Nickel (s)")
print(pennies, "penny (s)")
```

Answer (score 3):

You should update `total` after each coin:

```
half = total // 50
total = total % 50
# ...
```

This is because not all the coins are dividers of all the preceding coins. E.g. removing `25` from an amount changes its divisibility by `10`, so `total % 10` is not the same amount as `remainder_after_dimes` (if you had an odd number of quarters).

This could be done in a single step, using [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
half, total = divmod(total, 50)
quarter, total = divmod(total, 25)
dimes, total = divmod(total, 10)
nickels, total = divmod(total, 5)
pennies, total = divmod(total, 1)
```